# Add extensions in GutenBurg blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to add some extensions in `inspectControl` How can I add this. 
Please check the image for better understanding.
[Extensions Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U976.png)

Here is a code which I'm using but this one is not working. Can you please check it out what the problem. I'm not finding any documentation about this. Please refer and documentation or tutorial for this and please this code.

```
registerBlockType( 'hwb/grid-column',  {
title: __( 'Column' ),
parent: [ 'hwb/grid' ],
description: __( 'A single column within a grid block.' ),
icon: getIcon( 'block-grid-column' ),
category: 'mycategory',
supports: {
        styles: true,
        spacings: true,
        display: true,
        scrollReveal: true,
    },

// Other code like edit and save functions
}
```

Comment: @CarlosCavero Can you please check it now

Comment: Now it looks much more better. Hope someone can solve your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not the core extensions rather than it is created by **GhostKit**
You can enable in your plugin.

**Enable GhostKit Extension (Spacings)**

```
<?php
registerBlockType( 'my/block', {
    title: 'My block',
    ghostkit: {
        supports: {
            spacings: true,
        },
    },
    ...
} );
```

For more information [GhostKit Spacing Extension](https://ghostkit.io/extensions/spacings/)

Answer (score 0):

The "supports" property only supports these values out of the box: https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-registration/#supports-optional

If you want to create new sidebar panels then you'll want to use the InspectorControls component in your edit function, and whatever you put inside that will appear in the sidebar. Something like this:

```
const { PanelBody } = wp.components
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor
const { Fragment } = wp.element

edit(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody title="Panel Heading">
          <p>I will be in the sidebar</p>
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
      <p>I will be in the main content area.</p>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbars-and-inspector/

Comment: Yes, I know I can use the `InspectorControl` but if you see other plugins like **ghostkit** they are enable these extension maybe from core blocks. Please check the image also you see a little `EXT` infront of these controls. If you the code they are not adding anything for these extensions in `inspectorControl`